# Java: JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

Is it possible to make a progressbar in Java like displayed on this page?
[Image](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2007/12/22/ubuntu-gutsy-gibbon-progress-bar-screen.jpg).
So, not the default progressbar "filling-way".

If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it self. Just call `setIndeterminate(true);`!!

I found it on [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ProgressBarDemo2.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do some wicked overriding of either the paint or paintComponent methods (I forget which one exactly), but yeah it's possible.  The best way is to look at existing tutorials on custom swing components: h[ttp://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html)

They're pretty old, but still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to write your own custom component.  The alternative would be a custom look and feel (there's a lot of work involved in that), but it shouldn't be too difficult to write a custom component with your own indeterminate animation very similar to what you see there.

Comment: If your goal isn't the specific look, but just a generic indeterminate progress bar, more help is available here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html