# Java ProgressBar in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jprogressbar

i have a desktop GUI in swing , i want to show status of user storage used in the GUI, currently i am using JProgressBar, which is not much attractive, It seems like a simple progress bar.
Please suggest some attractive way to do.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632930/java-jprogressbar), as it may have an answer to your problem.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Comment: Just click on the JFreeChart [Memory Usage](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) tab.

Comment: @Sorrow, not sure an indeterminate jprogress bar is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: are you tried to change Look & Feel - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java

Comment: I'm not really sure what the OP wants as "some attractive way" is  subjective to the extreme.  Perhaps you should post a picture to indicate the desired goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for more attractive design. I could suggest you a couple of things:

1-Have a look at javaFX progress bars , you might find something interesting
http://download.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/tutorials/UIControls/progress.html

2-If you use the standar progress bar from the [java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) maybe you could try to edit it yourself. Have a look at this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CustomizingJProgressBarLookandFeel.htm)

Example of self customization:

```
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background",Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, just one thing, i use JavaFX with swing components. /

Comment: You're welcome. Here have a look at this: http://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/how_to_use_javafx_in